# JQuery autocomplete Ajax POST not sending data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:9000",
            data: {"name":"restrictedSearch", "id":$("#select").prop('selectedIndex'), "searchString":request.term, "intMatches": "0"},
            success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            console.log(item);
                            return {
                                label: item.term,
                                id: item.weight,
                            };
                        }));
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
});
```

And the html:

```
<div>
<select id="select">
    <option value="0">Search</option>
    <option value="1">Restricted Search</option>
    <option value="2">Best match</option>
    <option value="3">Weight of term</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="s">
      <input type="text" id="search">
</div>
```

With Chrome, nothing is posting to the server and none of the console.logs show up.
When I use the Eclipse inline browser I can see the json being returned in the console but nothing shows up in the HTML

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, any insight at all would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the network tab of Chrome's dev tools show?

Comment: It doesn't show anything at all, it always remains blank (after having loaded all the resources)

Comment: how about putting a console.log just before the ajax call, then you know that it's definitely handling the autocomplete event and running the `source` function? It looks like it should, but if nothing is working then test absolutely every possibility

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, that advice helped a lot. I went through every line meticulously to see what was working and what wasn't. It's all working now, but I'm not too sure why because it looks exactly the same to me.